# Cannot Find Type System.Resource.ResourceSet in module CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I downloaded the UWP BLE zip sample from Microsoft, [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/bluetoothle/).

Everything worked fine and I just want to check if the value received from my BLE device is a specific text or not by using `If` statement.

So I went and added codes like this to the `Scenario2_Client.xaml.cs`

```
private string SupremeTest(IBuffer buffer, GattPresentationFormat format)
        {
            byte[] data;
            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(buffer, out data);
            if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data) == "Test")
            {
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

But there's an error popped up upon deploying the project.

**Cannot find type System.Resources.ResourceSet in module CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary.**

What did I do wrong?

Comment: That ought to be a XAML error, look in the Output window for the full text of the message.  So nothing to do with the snippet you posted, or Bluetooth.

Comment: @HansPassant Hi!! Thank you. After you have given me the head up, I found out that `Using System.Windows.Forms` is causing the problem. It didn't state anything useful in the output though.

Comment: @HansPassant Btw is there a fortunate chance that you know how to import `System.Windows.Forms` to this UWP project?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms is not supported in uwp project. May I know why do you want to use System.Windows.Forms?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Sorry for the late reply, I require `System.Windows.Forms` because I wanted to use `SendKeys` to stimulate keyboard key press

Comment: As I said, the System.Windows.Forms is not supported in uwp project, but you could try to use [InputInjector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection.inputinjector?view=winrt-19041) class to achieve the similar functions as sendkeys.